# Join table with one datetime column related to multi datetime values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, left-join, one-to-many

Table 1:

| CustomerID | PurchaseDateTime |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | C1's PT1 |
| C1 | C1's PT2 |
| ... | ... |
| C1 | C1's PTn |
| C2 | C2's PT1 |
| C2 | C2's PT2 |
| ... | ... |

Table 2:

| CustomerID | ServiceDateTime |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | C1's ST1 |
| C1 | C1's ST2 |
| ... | ... |
| C1 | C1's STm |
| C2 | C2's ST1 |
| C2 | C2's ST2 |
| ... | ... |

I want to join them to a new table:

| CustomerID | PurchaseDateTime | ServiceDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | C1's PT1 | C1's ST1 |
| C1 | C1's PT1 | C1's ST2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| C1 | C1's PT1 | C1's STk |
| C1 | C1's PT2 | C1's STk+1 |
| C1 | C1's PT2 | C1's STk+2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

One PurchaseDateTime is related to multiple ServiceDateTimes. The earliest related ServiceDateTime is later than the PurchaseDateTime. The last related ServiceDateTime is earlier than the next PurchaseDateTime. All DateTimes in both tables are different.

So for example, for Customer1:

`PT1 < ST1 < ST2 < ... < STk < PT2 < STk+1... < STk+j < PT3 ...`

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    t1.CustomerID,
    t1.PurchaseDateTime,
    t2.ServiceDateTime
FROM 
    Table1 t1
JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
WHERE 
    t2.ServiceDateTime >= t1.PurchaseDateTime
    AND t2.ServiceDateTime <= (
        SELECT MIN(PurchaseDateTime)
        FROM Table1
        WHERE PurchaseDateTime > t1.PurchaseDateTime
        )
```

However, it does not give the one I would like to have.

How do I join to get the merged table above?

Comment: where does `C1's STk` and subsequent values come from. there are only data up to `C1's STm`..

Comment: also don't revert when someone fixed the table for you... its hard to read in the current form. it is correct to replace the SMSS with SQL Server given SMSS is just an interface for SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron Can you explain what result are trying to achieve with your WHERE Clause here?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: To pick up the missing value you can use `SELECT coalesce(MIN(PurchaseDateTime), t1.PurchaseDateTime)...` That works because you allow for equality though I'm not sure you really want to allow for ranges that overlap.

Comment: Either way just `coalesce()` the null as a future time that will then pass the test. That could be `dateadd(minute, 1, t1.PurchaseDateTime)` for example.

Comment: Code that does not work does not communicate what you wished or expected it to do. This post does explain how desired output is a function of inputs. ("join" & "related to" & "merged" mean nothing in particular.)

Answer (score 0):

On your correlated subquery you are missing to scope it down to the specific CustomerId.

```
    SELECT 
    t1.CustomerID,
    t1.PurchaseDateTime,
    t2.ServiceDateTime
FROM 
    Table1 t1
JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
WHERE 
    t2.ServiceDateTime >= t1.PurchaseDateTime
    AND t2.ServiceDateTime <= (
        SELECT MIN(PurchaseDateTime)
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE PurchaseDateTime > t1.PurchaseDateTime
        AND Table1.CustomerID=t1.CustomerID
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works but not for the last PurchasDateTime for each customer. Since at that time, no other PurchaseDateTime > the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
with T1Data as (
    select *, lead(t1.PurchaseDateTime) over (partition by t1.CustomerId order by t1.PurchaseDateTime) as nextPDT
    from Tables
)
select *
from T1Data as t1 inner join Table t2
    on  t2.ServiceDateTime > t1.PurchaseDateTime
        and (t2.ServiceDateTime < t1.nextPDT or t1.nextPDT is null);
```

Presumably it's not possible for both dates to be the same so equality tests aren't necessary. If you do want to allow that possibility, don't test for it at both ends of the range (as with the query in the question,) otherwise the service will become associated with two different purchases. In other words, the intervals shouldn't overlap.